# Output build of Maven

Tags: maven

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ABC</groupId>
<artifactId>ABCSPA</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <finalName>ABCSPA</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <port>8080</port>
                <path>${project.build.finalName}</path>
                <server>tomcatserver</server>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>admin</password>
                <additionalConfigFilesDir>${basedir}/src/main/tomcat/conf</additionalConfigFilesDir>
                <systemProperties>
                    <log4j.configuration>file:./src/main/tomcat/conf/log4j.xml</log4j.configuration>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.16</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-core-tiger</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <depenency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-remoting</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSon -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Utilities -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

The list of folders getting generated in pom.xml:

1. apache-tomcat-maven-plugin
2. classes
3. generated-sources
4. generated-test-sources
5. m2e-wtp
6. maven-archiver
7. maven-status
8. surefire
9. test-classes
10. ABCSPA
11. tomcat
12. ABCSPA.war

Can some one explain why all these folders are being generated? For example: in 'generated-sources', there is a folder 'annotation' which is an empty folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Maven, the `target` folder is intended to be the working build directory of Maven. This folder is inherently temporary. The logic is that this folder contains **generated** data, i.e. data that Maven creates at build-time. Never should you store permanent data inside this folder (the corollary is that the entries of that folder should *never* be version-controlled). Since this data will be generated, it should be safe to delete it before the build.

Quoting from [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#What_is_a_POM):

> Examples for this is the build directory, which is `target`.

This directory is defined in the [Super POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM), which means all Maven projects (unless they override the property `project.build.directory`), will have this folder.

As such, what gets generated in it during the build depends only on what your POM is and how your build is happening. It would be too broad to try to explain all the entries in there (and I'm sure a lot of those aren't even documented as they are really temporary internal details of each plugin). There a few entries inside that will be common though:

- the `maven-compiler-plugin` will generate by default the folder `generated-sources/annotations` because that's the default value for the property [`generatedSourcesDirectory`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#generatedSourcesDirectory)
- `target/classes` corresponds to the `project.build.outputDirectory` of the Super POM. It will contain all the generated classes by the `maven-compiler-plugin`.
- the `maven-war-plugin` will generated the war by default inside this folder because that's the default value of the [`outputDirectory`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#outputDirectory) attribute.

Since this folder is supposed to remain temporary, the [`maven-clean-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/) has the purpose of cleaning it:

> `clean:clean` attempts to clean a project's working directory of the files that we're generated at build-time. By default, it discovers and deletes the directories configured in `project.build.directory`, `project.build.outputDirectory`, `project.build.testOutputDirectory`, and `project.reporting.outputDirectory`.

Note that it is a good practice to invoke the `maven-clean-plugin` to delete those working directories before each build (not doing it can lead to weird compile behaviour, like being able to compile code that shouldn't be).

---

A special note about the folder `m2e-wtp`: this is [M2Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) specific folder. Its presence is only tied to this Eclipse Plugin integrating Maven (so it is not linked to Maven itself per se).

Comment: Thanks a lot Tunaki :) Could you please tell why 'maven-status', 'maven-archiver' and 'apache-tomcat-maven-plugin' empty folder are geneerated?

Comment: @Meenakshi Those are probably generated the [Maven Archiver](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/) when creating the WAR. But as I said, don't worry too much about that. It's an implementation detail.